# high chart with large variates data and dynamically create y axis

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am creating High charts with large variation of data as high charts does not display minimum data I used logs for changing data here is my code its working fine but y axis doesn't works fine Here's Link  http://jsfiddle.net/rutup/6hxPU/

```
    function createBarChart(source, title, placeHolderId, sideText, xColumnValue) {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors:["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c","#d62728","#9467bd","#8c564b","#e377c2","#7f7f7f", "#bcbd22", "#17becf"]// ["#4572a7", "#aa4643", "#89a54e", "#80699b"]
});
$('#' + placeHolderId).highcharts({
    credits: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    exporting: { enabled: false },
    title: {
        text: title
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: xColumnValue
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
       // tickInterval:
        lineWidth: 1,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: sideText
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'gray'
            }
            , formatter: function () {
                return this.y;
            }
            //, formatter: function () {
            //    return calcTotalAntiLog(this.total);//this.total;
            //}
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + calcAntiLog(this.y) //+ '<br/>' +//calcAntiLog(this.y)
            // 'Total: ' + calcAntiLog(this.point.stackTotal);//calcAntiLog(this.point.stackTotal)
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'white',
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return calcAntiLog(this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: source
});

}
```

Comment: Well, I see 4 points in your series object, and 4 columns are displayed, so what is wrong?

Comment: @Rutu, could you add some punctuation marks to your text? Sorry, but you should spend at least a few seconds to format your text before sending..

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan that's fine that it shows 4 points just look at the y axis data and interval it shows 5 as max while actual max data is 100 i want to set y axis data interval as per my data

Comment: @Paweł Fus i am sorry for that i formatted code please have a look

Comment: I don't mean code, I mean your question - it's not clear what does work and what doesn't.. maybe I need a coffee. Anyway, calcLog(100000) => 12.51, and this is displayed on yAxis. Can't you just remove that strange calculations and pass true data? Then set yAxis.type = logarithmic.

Comment: @Rutu you can use tickPositions or tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis which allow set set array ticks in customised positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using a logarithmic axis and letting highcharts calculate the log? 
In yAxis settings set `type: 'logarithmic'` 
I've modified your fiddle to show that in action http://jsfiddle.net/6hxPU/7/